# TeXnicCenter won't auto-suggest Bibtex keys

Tags: bibtex, citing, auto-completion

I'm blocked with an issue here. I think I've tried everything so I'm desperate enough to open this post.

Basically, I am working with a `.bib` file for my bibliography in **TeXnicCenter**. Everything is fine except that when I digit the `\cite` command nothing pops up to suggest me any of the keys included in the `.bib` file. I also have nothing under my *Biliography tab* nor under *Files* (there should be my `.bib`file there no?). 
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font = small, format = hang]{caption}
\newenvironment{citazione}
{\begin{quotation}\small}
{\end{quotation}}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file:

```
@BOOK{lamport94,
  author={Leslie Lamport},
  title={A Document Preparation System},
  note={User's Guide and Reference Manual},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley},
  edition={Second}
}
@BOOK{knuth84:poesie,
  author={An Authos},
  title={The book},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
```

Also adding some screenshots hoping to help you visualize the problem better:
[image: note that everything is empty in the Bibligraphy & Files tab]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. Apparently you can get the auto-suggestion pop up only if you work within a Project (Menu - New - Project - etc.). And if you have to force it just use Parse Structure under Project menu. The thing didn't work for just a simple File (at least for me).

That's all. Thanks anyway.